# How to get colored datagridview headers with the 3D looking style

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, header, styles

I'm using the Winform datagridview and try to customize my headers by changing the backcolor.
In order to be able to modify the color, I must set the **EnableHeadersVisualStyles** property to false.

But when I set this property, I'm loosing the default 3D theme. Do you know if there is any workaround to save the 3D style and have the colored header?

My code:

```
dataGridTaxes.EnableHeadersVisualStyles = false;
dataGridTaxes.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle = BlueDataGridHeaderStyle.GetInstance();
```

where BlueDataGridHeaderStyle is just a basic style with the new BackColor

Comment: Its all or nothing. Use the theming you get provided from the system via Visual Styles or paint yourself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to customize your `DataGridView`, here is a sample code I made for you. It looks really good compared with the default 3D style of `ColumnHeader` but supports `BackColor` and `Hover backcolor`:

```
    //CellPainting event handler for your dataGridView1
    private void dataGridView1_CellPainting(object sender, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e){
        if (e.RowIndex == -1 && e.ColumnIndex > -1){
            e.PaintBackground(e.CellBounds, true);
            RenderColumnHeader(e.Graphics, e.CellBounds, e.CellBounds.Contains(hotSpot) ? hotSpotColor : backColor);
            RenderColumnHeaderBorder(e.Graphics, e.CellBounds, e.ColumnIndex);
            using (Brush brush = new SolidBrush(e.CellStyle.ForeColor)){
                using (StringFormat sf = new StringFormat() {LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center, Alignment = StringAlignment.Center}) {
                    e.Graphics.DrawString(e.Value.ToString(), e.CellStyle.Font, brush, e.CellBounds, sf);                        
                }
            }
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
    Color hotSpotColor = Color.LightGreen;//For hover backcolor
    Color backColor = Color.LimeGreen;    //For backColor    
    Point hotSpot;
    private void RenderColumnHeader(Graphics g, Rectangle headerBounds, Color c) {
        int topHeight = 10;
        Rectangle topRect = new Rectangle(headerBounds.Left, headerBounds.Top+1, headerBounds.Width, topHeight);
        RectangleF bottomRect = new RectangleF(headerBounds.Left, headerBounds.Top+1 + topHeight, headerBounds.Width, headerBounds.Height- topHeight-4);            
        Color c1 = Color.FromArgb(180, c);            
        using (SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(c1)) {
            g.FillRectangle(brush, topRect);
            brush.Color = c;
            g.FillRectangle(brush, bottomRect);
        }
    }
    private void RenderColumnHeaderBorder(Graphics g, Rectangle headerBounds, int colIndex) {            
        g.DrawRectangle(new Pen(Color.White, 0.1f), headerBounds.Left + 0.5f, headerBounds.Top + 0.5f,headerBounds.Width-1f,headerBounds.Height-1f);
        ControlPaint.DrawBorder(g, headerBounds, Color.Gray, 0, ButtonBorderStyle.Inset,
                                               Color.Gray, 0, ButtonBorderStyle.Inset,
                                             Color.Gray, colIndex != dataGridView1.ColumnCount - 1 ? 1 : 0, ButtonBorderStyle.Inset,
                                           Color.Gray, 1, ButtonBorderStyle.Inset);
    }
    //MouseMove event handler for your dataGridView1
    private void dataGridView1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e){
        hotSpot = e.Location;
    }
    //MouseLeave event handler for your dataGridView1
    private void dataGridView1_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e){
        hotSpot = Point.Empty;
    }
```

[image]

You can implement the `RenderColumnHeaderBorder` as the followings using `ControlPaint.DrawBorder3D` instead, it's much simpler:

```
private void RenderColumnHeaderBorder(Graphics g, Rectangle headerBounds, int colIndex)
{
    ControlPaint.DrawBorder3D(g, headerBounds, Border3DStyle.Raised, Border3DSide.All & ~Border3DSide.Middle);
}
```

[image]

```
private void RenderColumnHeaderBorder(Graphics g, Rectangle headerBounds, int colIndex)
{
    ControlPaint.DrawBorder3D(g, headerBounds, Border3DStyle.RaiseInner, Border3DSide.All & ~Border3DSide.Middle);
}
```

[image]

```
private void RenderColumnHeaderBorder(Graphics g, Rectangle headerBounds, int colIndex)
{
    ControlPaint.DrawBorder3D(g, headerBounds, Border3DStyle.RaiseOuter, Border3DSide.All & ~Border3DSide.Middle);
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer! it's pretty interesting but doesn't work with my code. 
I have several issues: If I set EnableHeadersVisualStyles to true, I have the 3D renderer but I lose the forecolor (which was setted to White) otherwise I don’t see the 3D renderer. And in all cases, the first header is highlighted until I move the mouse hover which is pretty ugly.

Comment: I just added a default value to the hotspot and it solves the last issue: Point hotSpot = new Point(-1, -1);

Comment: @michael.irsutti I updated the code in `CellPainting` to support `ForeColor`, you have to keep `EnableHeadersVisualStyles = true`, change the forecolor by `ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle`, for the issue you mentioned, **I don't have problem with that issue**, it's a little strange.

Comment: With your update and my little change above, it works perfectly. Thank you so much!

Comment: @michael.irsutti you're welcome, the code **is just a demo sample** for you to get started with customizing control in `winforms`, you should try understanding it and customize it yourself.

Comment: I already customized it :-) and my most important change was to replace the Point.Empty by new Point(-1, -1) otherwise when you came back on your control (I'm in a tabControl) the first column header is highlighted (because Location (0,0 ) is inside your first header)